# How do you set up a default route to an area?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a folder called areas, in it I have 2 folders (Admin and Portal). How would I need to set up my Default route so when I start the site at the root site it routes it to Portal/Home/Index action?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose [**THIS**](https://forums.asp.net/p/1549680/3800343.aspx) is what You are looking for.

And this is how it looks =>
[image]

But there might be better approach. This is more like hack.

Comment: When I do the above, I get this when running the program.

"An item with the same key has already been added."